# Redirect multiple domains and subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: domain, https, htaccess, subdomain

I am struggling with setting proper https redirect via a .htaccess file for my domains. I have the following domains, subdomains and directories:

```
public_html/     -> www.red.com
public_html/drk  -> dark.red.com
public_html/blue -> www.blue.com
```

How am I supposed to write the .htaccess file(s) so that the redirect works properly?

Currently I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?red\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://red.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dark\.red\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://dark.red.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blue\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://blue.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Redirect works for the main site (www.red.com) but not for the other two sites. If I remove the rules for the other two sites, redirect sends me to www.red.com/drk instead of dark.red.com and to www.red.com/blue instead of www.blue.com.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  If you are just trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, why do you think you can't do it with a single ruleset matching HTTP and rewriting for HTTPS?

Comment: I tried with a single rule but I got inaccurate redirects. How would a correct single rule look like?